# TCP hash tables in Linux Kernel

Tags: networking, kernel, debugging, sockets

I have implemented a solution to migrate sockets between servers running Linux OS. The migration mechanism works very well and the client is capable of continuing receiving his service from the new server. The solution consists of two parts: a user space process and a Linux Kernel module. Currently I have only one problem, when the importing server tries to close the migrated socket, the whole machine freezes. Whereas when the client does the closing, the importing machine does not hang directly, it hangs after afew trials. I was able to dump the kernel and get the error log. After some inspections, I believe that I am missing adding the migrated socket to a hash table in the Linux Kernel. Currently I am adding the TCP connection to the following hash table only.

```
int tcp_hash_add(struct sock *sk) {
    sk->sk_prot->hash(sk);
}
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what I am missing in the importing side? I think that in a normal server-client TCP application, when the client sends a request to the server. The server creates an independent socket to that connection, and it obtains some correlation information between the original listening socket and the accepted socket. And this is might be what I am missing the importing side.

**Linux Kernel Dump:**

```
[  225.717049] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000020
[  225.720544] IP: [<ffffffff8162056c>] __inet_twsk_hashdance+0x8c/0x160    
[  225.720544] PGD 7bbf9067 PUD 7b7fc067 PMD 0                              
[  225.720544] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP                         
[  225.720544] Modules linked in: sockmi(OF) nf_conntrack(F) vesafb(F) vboxsf(OF) snd_int)
[  225.720544] CPU 0                                       
[  225.720544] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/0 Tainted: GF       W  O 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precisx
[  225.720544] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8162056c>]  [<ffffffff8162056c>] __inet_twsk_hashdance0
[  225.720544] RSP: 0018:ffff88007fc039d0  EFLAGS: 00010282
[  225.720544] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff88005cbd5000 RCX: ffffffff81e304c0
[  225.720544] RDX: 0000000000001c37 RSI: 0000000000000082 RDI: 0000000000000009
[  225.720544] RBP: ffff88007fc03a00 R08: 000000000000000a R09: 0000000000000000
[  225.720544] R10: 000000000000021a R11: 0000000000000219 R12: ffff88007ba4b800         
[  225.720544] R13: ffffc9000035a7d0 R14: ffffc90000322500 R15: ffff88007c1e3d40         
[  225.720544] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88007fc00000(0000) knlGS:000000000000000
[  225.720544] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b                         
[  225.720544] CR2: 0000000000000020 CR3: 000000007965f000 CR4: 00000000000006f0         
[  225.720544] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000         
[  225.720544] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  225.720544] Process swapper/0 (pid: 0, threadinfo ffffffff81c00000, task ffffffff81c15)
[  225.720544] Stack:                                                                    
[  225.720544]  ffff88007ba4b800 ffff88007ba4b800 ffff88005cbd5000 0000000000000000      
[  225.720544]  000000000000001f 0000000000000000 ffff88007fc03a50 ffffffff8163de3c      
[  225.720544]  ffff8800000000d9 000000065cb8b300 ffff88003652e262 ffff88007ba4b800      
[  225.720544] Call Trace:                                                               
[  225.720544]  <IRQ>                                                                    
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8163de3c>] tcp_time_wait+0x1bc/0x290                           
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8162d4fe>] tcp_fin+0x10e/0x1c0                                 
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8162e078>] tcp_data_queue+0x3e8/0x580                          
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff81631bb5>] tcp_rcv_state_process+0x2b5/0x6b0                   
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8163abc7>] tcp_v4_do_rcv+0xc7/0x220                            
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8163c829>] tcp_v4_rcv+0x569/0x830                              
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff81616366>] ip_local_deliver_finish+0xe6/0x280                  
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8161668a>] ip_local_deliver+0x4a/0x90
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff81616039>] ip_rcv_finish+0x119/0x360                           
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff816168ed>] ip_rcv+0x21d/0x300                                  
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff815e355a>] __netif_receive_skb+0x5fa/0x760                     
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff8163cbae>] ? tcp4_gro_receive+0x9e/0x110                       
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff815e36e3>] netif_receive_skb+0x23/0x90                         
[  225.720544]  [<ffffffff815e3e28>] napi_gro_receive+0xe8/0x140                         
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffffa0002f98>] e1000_clean_rx_irq+0x2b8/0x520 [e1000]              
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff8144df56>] ? credit_entropy_bits.part.7+0x176/0x1d0            
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffffa0004801>] e1000_clean+0x51/0xc0 [e1000]                       
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff815e4cd4>] net_rx_action+0x134/0x260                           
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81045136>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10                         
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81062620>] __do_softirq+0xc0/0x240                             
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff8103cca2>] ? ack_apic_level+0x72/0x130                         
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff816fdd5c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30                              
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81016775>] do_softirq+0x65/0xa0                                
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff810628fe>] irq_exit+0x8e/0xb0                                  
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff816fe5f3>] do_IRQ+0x63/0xe0                                    
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff816f406d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d                          
[  225.906423]  <EOI>                                                                    
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81084008>] ? hrtimer_start+0x18/0x20                           
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81045136>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff8101cc33>] default_idle+0x53/0x1f0                             
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff8101dad9>] cpu_idle+0xd9/0x120                                 
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff816c6db2>] rest_init+0x72/0x80                                 
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81d05c4f>] start_kernel+0x3d1/0x3de                            
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81d057ff>] ? pass_bootoption.constprop.2+0xd3/0xd3             
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81d05397>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x131/0x135               
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81d05120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120                    
[  225.906423]  [<ffffffff81d05468>] x86_64_start_kernel+0xcd/0xdc                       
[  225.906423] Code: 49 c1 e5 04 4c 03 6a 18 4c 89 ef e8 2f 35 0d 00 49 8b 84 24 60 03 00
[  225.906423] RIP  [<ffffffff8162056c>] __inet_twsk_hashdance+0x8c/0x160                
[  225.906423]  RSP <ffff88007fc039d0>                                                   
[  225.906423] CR2: 0000000000000020                                                     
[  226.111238] ---[ end trace 18ecfe1006daa681 ]---                                      
[  226.111817] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

Comment: This is something you should be asking on the Linux Kernel [mailing list](http://www.tux.org/lkml/), more specifically the `netdev` list.

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I am interested in implementing the same.